# Principally, is input type="text" instead input type="url" a security problem for "website" form fields?

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML-PHP-CSS contact form (no JavaScript) with some trivial fields sent via PHP's `mail()` function. One of the fields is "website" field in which a user should input a website domain (if relevant).

---

If I add to the form field with `input type="url"` it obligates users to add a protocol prefix such as `http://` or `https://` to any website domain or full URL.

Most users don't even think about adding a protocol prefix and would get an error for lacking it and the form won't be submitted without it (some users might not understand the error) so accessibilitywise I have figured that I shouldn't use `input type="url"` at all and should find another kind of input field to ask for a website domain.

---

I thought about changing `type="url"` to `type="text"`.

Perhaps there are some security considerations if one takes that approach.

Principally, is `input type="text"` instead `input type="url"` a security problem for "website" form fields?

Answer (score 1):

The **type of the input field is not a security feature** but merely a usability feature, i.e. it allows early checking of value and might offer already constrains when entering the data in the browser. The server must still validate that the input conforms to the expected type since it is easily possible to bypass the browser based verification or not use an browser at all to submit the input.

Based on this, it is not a security problem to specify type `text` instead of type `url` for the input field, but might merely be a usability problem. It gets a security problem only when the server side application blindly assumes that the input will only be of the specific type, i.e. blindly trusts client input based on the wrong assumption that the browser will check it properly.

Comment: I thank you for the answer. Some parts of it were unclear to me; as a first step of ensuring understanding I tried to split it into two contextual passages and minorly changed the phrasing ; now (in the suggested edit), assuming I got the meaning correctly, I only have slight trouble to understand the second passage.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/166285

Comment: @timesharer: It might not be a good idea to edit the answer if you don't fully understand it yet. Your edits did not actually improve the answer, that's why I rejected these. It might be better to ask for clarification of the parts you don't understand and be as specific as possible about what you don't understand, instead of just stating that you *"have slight trouble to understand the second passage"*.

Comment: Okay, accepted; either way I wasn't also sure I understood passage. I really think that the bolding is redundant...

Comment: The first passage*